# Excel WRAPROWS to convert multiple colums into multiple rows in excel using functions

Tags: function, excel-formula

I'm trying to convert multiple 30-long rows into pockets of 6-long rows wrapping around into 6 by 5 blocks, I know you can use something like "=WRAPROWS(B1:AE1,6)" for each row but how can I make it go automatically forever?
I know there must be some ways of doing that using functions and formulas but I can't figure it out!  Tnx
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this formula:

`=WRAPROWS(TOCOL(B1:AE13),6)`

It will first make one long column which is then wrapped into rows.

Comment: Ike! you're a Champ! thanks a lot!